# Placing figures in parboxes and referencing them

Tags: xetex, cross-referencing, environments

I'm trying to build a latex environment that generates a table, and in that table there may be figures that need to be referenced. I absolutely need the number in the text to compile to the reference number. Ideally this would also have the hyperlink to the figure, but that's secondary. (If l have to define a separate counter that's fine).

```
%% simple.sty
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage[table]{xcolor}

\newenvironment{statementtable}{
  \newcommand{\statement}[2]{
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{white} ##1} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{gray!25} \parbox{6in}{##2}} \\ \hline
  }
  \newcommand{\statementfigure}[3]{
    \stepcounter{figure}
    \phantomsection ##3 \label{##1} \\
    Figure \arabic{figure}: ##2
  }  
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|} \hline
}{
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}

}
```

The tex file is as such

```
%% simple.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{simple}

\begin{document}
\begin{statementtable}
  \statement{statement}{lorem ipsem see \ref{fig:foo} and \ref{fig:bar}}
  \statement{figures}{\statementfigure{fig:foo}{foo}{\includegraphics{potato.png}} \\
    \statementfigure{fig:bar}{bar}{\includegraphics{potato.png}}}
\end{statementtable}

\end{document}
```

And the output from `xelatex simple.tex` is missing the actual numbers. How do I get `\ref` to include the value of a counter *at* a label?

[image: current output]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first glance, changing `\stepcounter{figure}` to `\refstepcounter{figure}` seems like it should suffice to fix the problem. For sure, the outputs of the `\ref` directives are no longer empty once you make that change.

*However*, some additional sleuthing reveals that `hyperref` is under the impression that what's being referenced are entities of type `section` rather than of type `figure`. Rather than keep re-inventing the wheel, so to say, I suggest you start using some of the machinery of the well-debugged `caption` package -- specifically, its `\captionof` and `\captionsetup` macros.

Incidentally, I wouldn't use a fixed width, such as `6in`, for the `\parbox`. Instead, let LaTeX calculate the width such that no overflow into the right-hand margin occurs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{caption} % for "\captionof" and "\captionsetup" macros
\usepackage{array}   % for "\extrarowheight" length parameter

%%% --- contents of simple.sty --- %%%
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage[table]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,allcolors=blue} % optional
\usepackage[nameinlink,capitalize,noabbrev]{cleveref} % optional

\newenvironment{statementtable}{%
  \begingroup 
  \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a slightly more open "look"
  \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false,
                justification=raggedright,
                skip=0pt}
  \newcommand{\statement}[2]{%
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{white} ##1} \\ 
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{gray!25}%
      \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}{##2}} \\ 
    \hline
  }
  \newcommand{\statementfigure}[3]{%
    \phantomsection ##3 
    \captionof{figure}{##2} \label{##1}
  }  
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|} 
  \hline
  }{%
  \end{tabular}
  \endgroup
}
%%% --- end contents of simple.sty --- %%%

\begin{document}
\begin{statementtable}
  \statement{statement}{See \cref{fig:foo,fig:bar}.}
  \statement{figures}{%
    \statementfigure{fig:foo}{foo}{\includegraphics{potato.png}}
    \statementfigure{fig:bar}{bar}{\includegraphics{potato.png}}}
\end{statementtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I really like that you told the OP of the first answer first how they could improve their answer, and gave them time to do that, before adding your ("competing") answer!

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat - Thanks!

Comment: That seems a lot less kludgy. One note, the `\phantomsection` l'd had previously is no longer necessary. (there's an edit in the pipe to fix that).

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `\refstepcounter` instead of `\stepcounter`.

Comment: Changing `\stepcounter` to `\refstepcounter` is a step in the right direction, but it's not the full solution. E.g., if you replace `\ref` with `\autoref`, the chosen label is "section", not "figure".